# How to group a legend or get seperate legends by facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a dataset that I am presenting facetted by region and then using sub region as a fill. I have defined the colours using a separate named variable relating to the names of the subregion. I am wondering if it is possible to make the legend itself grouped in a similar way to the facet to make it easier to interpret.

The named sub_region variable

```
sub_region_colours <- c("South America" = "#0570b0", "Western Africa" = "#8c96c6", "Central America" = "#74a9cf", "Eastern Africa" = "#8856a7", "Northern Africa" = "#edf8fb", "Middle Africa" = "#b3cde3", "Southern Africa" = "#810f7c", "Northern America" = "#f1eef6", "Caribbean" = "#bdc9e1", "Eastern Asia" = "#bd0026", "Southern Asia" = "#fd8d3c", "South-Eastern Asia" = "#f03b20", "Southern Europe" = "#238b45", "Australia and New Zealand" = "#ce1256", "Melanesia" = "#df65b0", "Micronesia" = "#d7b5d8", "Polynesia" = "#f1eef6", "Central Asia" = "#fecc5c", "Western Asia" = "#ffffb2", "Eastern Europe" = "#66c2a4", "Northern Europe" = "#edf8fb", "Western Europe" = "#b2e2e2", "Small Islands" = "#252525")
```

This is the head(exporting_countries) grouping by sender_iso3, year and sender_region removed.

```
structure(list(sender_iso3 = c("ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", 
"ABW"), year = c(2005, 2011, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017), sender_region = c("Americas", 
"Americas", "Americas", "Americas", "Americas", "Americas"), 
    sender_subregion = c("Caribbean", "Caribbean", "Caribbean", 
    "Caribbean", "Caribbean", "Caribbean"), export = c(1, 1, 
    4, 5, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Finally this is the code for the current plot

```
  geom_bar()+
  labs(title = "Number of countries reporting export of chickens",
       fill = "Subregion")+
  facet_wrap(~ sender_region)+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Year", limits = c(1986, 2017), breaks = c(1986, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2017), guide = guide_axis(angle = 90))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = sub_region_colours)+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
```

Which at the moment produces this:

[Graph with less than ideal legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck8tT.png)

It would be great if I can group the legend fill colours similarly to the facets which would make it easier to read off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to achieve this would be to make seperate plots for each region and make use of `patchwork` to glue the plots together. A second approach would be to make use of the `ggnewscale` package which allows to have multiple fill (or ...) scales and legends in one plot.

However, similiar to using `patchwork` the approach using `ggnewscale` package could become a bit tedious as it requires to split the data according to the number of facets and plot each dataset via seperate layers. Therefore my solution adds a helper function which 1) splits the data and sets up the layers for each region or facet and 2) can be used to loop over the regions via e.g. `lapply`.

BTW: As your sample data included only one region I added a second region.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

sub_region_colours <- c("South America" = "#0570b0", "Western Africa" = "#8c96c6", "Central America" = "#74a9cf", "Eastern Africa" = "#8856a7", "Northern Africa" = "#edf8fb", "Middle Africa" = "#b3cde3", "Southern Africa" = "#810f7c", "Northern America" = "#f1eef6", "Caribbean" = "#bdc9e1", "Eastern Asia" = "#bd0026", "Southern Asia" = "#fd8d3c", "South-Eastern Asia" = "#f03b20", "Southern Europe" = "#238b45", "Australia and New Zealand" = "#ce1256", "Melanesia" = "#df65b0", "Micronesia" = "#d7b5d8", "Polynesia" = "#f1eef6", "Central Asia" = "#fecc5c", "Western Asia" = "#ffffb2", "Eastern Europe" = "#66c2a4", "Northern Europe" = "#edf8fb", "Western Europe" = "#b2e2e2", "Small Islands" = "#252525")

d <- structure(list(sender_iso3 = c(
  "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW",
  "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW"
), year = c(
  2005,
  2011, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2005, 2011, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017
), sender_region = c(
  "Americas", "Americas", "Americas", "Americas",
  "Americas", "Americas", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa",
  "Africa", "Africa"
), sender_subregion = c(
  "Caribbean", "Caribbean",
  "Caribbean", "Caribbean", "Caribbean", "Caribbean", "Southern Africa",
  "Southern Africa", "Southern Africa", "Southern Africa", "Southern Africa",
  "Southern Africa"
), export = c(
  1, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5,
  2, 1
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
regions <- unique(d$sender_region)

# Layers for each region
make_layers <- function(x) {
  d <- filter(d, sender_region == regions[[x]])

  list(
    if (x != 1) new_scale_fill(),
    geom_bar(data = d, aes(x = year, fill = sender_subregion)),
    scale_fill_manual(
      values = sub_region_colours,
      guide = guide_legend(
        order = x,
        title = regions[x],
        title.position = "top"
      )
    )
  )
}
p <- ggplot() +
  lapply(seq_along(regions), make_layers)

# Add theme and wrap
p +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = "Year", limits = c(1986, 2017),
    breaks = c(1986, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2017),
    guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~sender_region)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. Sorry about the repro data, shouldn't have used head.